# Pretty Print a json file when returning in a flask function

Tags: python, json, flask

I am looking to figure out how I can pretty print a json file when I return it in a flask function. I have managed to pretty print it using json.dump but not with the flask function. this is what I have":

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import flask
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

with open('VO/IFATC EG/qotd.json') as qotd_file:
    data = json.load(qotd_file)

    rr = data['questions']
    car = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    print(car)

@app.route('/')
def words():
    return json.dumps(data, indent=4)

app.run()
```

it prints car but I just get

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a config option `JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR` which allows you to do this.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import flask
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR"] = True

with open('VO/IFATC EG/qotd.json') as qotd_file:
    data = json.load(qotd_file)

    rr = data['questions']
    car = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    print(car)

@app.route('/')
def words():
    return jsonify(data)

app.run()
```

Note that the return uses `jsonify` instead of `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 0):

In your html, put it beween these tags:

`<pre><code>your_return_json here</code></pre>`

Suggestion: use jinja2 html template en return render_template

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template
import flask
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

with open('VO/IFATC EG/qotd.json') as qotd_file:
    data = json.load(qotd_file)

    rr = data['questions']
    car = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    print(car)

@app.route('/')
def words():
    return render_template('your_template.html from a templates subfolder', data=json.dumps(data, indent=4))

app.run()
```

and a template.html file in a folder templates/ with contents:

```
<pre><code>{{ data }}</code></pre>
```

Comment: That is not JSON but a HTML document displaying a representation of JSON then